# How do you create a PageFieldFilterWebPart by PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I'm trying to create a PageFieldFilterWebPart by PowerShell. If I use the PageContextFilterWebPart I success to create it, but I can't configure it. Anyone who have done this? If I success with this I also wan't to connect this to a document web part.

```
$WebUrl = "[weburl]"
$PageUrl = "[pageurl]"
$ZoneName = "Zon1"
$ZoneIndex = "1"

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $WebUrl

$webPart = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PageContextFilterWebPart
$webPart.ParameterName = "Category" # Error: 'ParameterName' is a ReadOnly property.
$webPart.FilterName = "Category"

$page = $web.GetFile($PageUrl)
$page.CheckOut()

$webpartmanager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($PageUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$webpartmanager.AddWebPart($WebPart, $ZoneName, $ZoneIndex);

$page.CheckIn("")

$web.Dispose()
```

Is this the way to go or is there another?